# Push Notifications in WebView android app

Tags: android, webview, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I have a requirement where I want to send push notifications to the user.
For example

> the app will have 2 users. If user 1 send a friend request to user 2
>   then user 2 should get a notification like " You got friend request
>   from user 1" and when user 2 clicks on that notification he should
>   able to see the user 1 profile.

I know how to do all these with the activities but here I am using web view, so please help me to solve with this. Any help is appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

You can always access your Java code trough javascrtipt running on the web page your WebView is presenting. You can define a Java method (which sends the notification through your backend) and call it from your custom javascript.

Take a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: this means i should have a java method which runs in background to catch any data posted by backend? If so then background running will consume lot of battery right?